# Jenkins and gitlab multibranch pupeline

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-plugins

I'm using jenkins and gitlab for my pipeline. Communication and made via Jenkins git plugin. How do I get the values description, author, author email from a merge request via web hook? For the hoook web, I use the gitlab plugin and it works fine.

My pipeline use multibranch and script pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the available variables here: [Environmentals variables for git plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/#environment-variables)

In case that you need more information, I recommend that you install the GitLab plugin. It exposes this variables: [Defined variables in GitLab plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#defined-variables)

Once you get the variable you can use for modify the build description, send a notification, or do whatever you need